# Firebase Security Rules - Error getting document: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm writing a react application that signs in a user via Google/Facebook using firebase auth and then looks to create a user in the users table if the user doc is not yet in the firestore users table. Per the following code:

```
function loginSocial(provider) {
    return auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((res) => {

    //we've signed in and we now want to check if the doc exists in the db
    
    console.log(user.uid, auth.currentUser.uid); 

    var docRef = app.firestore().collection('users', res.user.uid)

    docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    
      if (doc.exists) {
        //if the doc exists then we don't do anything
      } else {
       //code to create user
      }
```

The issue is that the `docRef.get()` call is failing - from the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

But my firebase rules should be letting it through as I understand it:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      // allow users to read/update their own document
      allow read, update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    // allow user to modify collections nested under their own document
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas why this would be failing and what I can do instead?

Note this is what I see in the console:

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `user.uid`?  We can't see where it comes from or what it is, and that it's the exact same as the currently signed in user's UID.

Comment: @DougStevenson added it above, I simplified the code when I copied it over but its just res.user

Comment: At first glance your code looks fine. Are you sure this is the code that causes the error? If so, can you add `console.log(res.user.uid, auth.currentUser.uid);` right before you call Firestore, and show the updated code and its output in the question?

Comment: that console.log logs the same uid for both @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated above

Comment: Ok what I've got working now is just to catch the error and add the doc anyway in the catch segment. It's not clean and feels wrong but its working now.

Comment: Nevermind - this workaround does not work, next time I try to read the doc I hit the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code that ended up working for me, this might be an issue of me using an outdated firebase version

```
var colRef = app.firestore().collection('users')

colRef.doc(user.uid).get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
      }
      else{
        //create user
      }
    })
```